# Intersection numbers via residue formula

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory, equivariant-cohomology

$\newcommand{\sslash}{\mathbin{/\mkern-7mu/}}$With a friend we are trying to understand residue formulas in the article "Cohomology pairings on singular quotients in geometric invariant theory" by Jeffrey, Kiem, Kirwan and Woolf.

Let $G = SL_2$ acting on $\Bbb P^n = Sym^n(\Bbb P^1)$, and $X = \Bbb P^n \sslash  SL_2$. For $n=5$, this space should be a surface. The Poincaré polynomial is $1+t^2+t^4$ (We suspect that $X \cong \Bbb P^2$).

I want to compute the cup-product $H^2(X) \otimes H^2(X) \to H^4(X)$. This cup-product should be given by an integer number, since by Poincaré duality it should correspond to the self-intersection $C^2$ (where $C$ is the dual of the generator of $H^2(X)$. $X$ might be singular but it has at worst orbifold singularity so Poincaré duality still holds).

Let us write $\xi$ for the hyperplane class in $\Bbb P^5$. Then, according to the article we should get $$ \langle \xi \cup \xi, [X] \rangle = -\text{Res}_{x=0} (4x^2(f_1(x) + f_2(x) + f_3(x)))$$ where $$ f_1(x) =  \frac{(5x)^2}{(-5x-5x)(5x-3x)(-5x - x)(-5x+x)(-5x+3x)}$$ $$ f_2(x) = \frac{(3x)^2}{(-3x-5x)(-3x-3x)(-3x-x)(-3x+x)(-3x+5x)}$$ $$f_3(x) = \frac{x^2}{(-x-5x)(-x-3x)(-x-x)(-x+3x)(-x+5x)}  $$

The sum is over the positive (with respect to the moment map) fixed points of the torus action, the denominator is the equivariant Euler class.

We computed that this residue is $\frac{-1}{96}$, that seems completely wrong. We couldn't get a meaningful answer for $n=3$ as well. However we checked that the formula works in a non-trivial example.

If someone could explain how to use correctly the formula in the case $X = \mathbb P^5 \sslash SL_2$, it would be great.

We have a guess where the mistake could be : we assumed that the Kirwan map was sending $\xi$ to the class of $C$, but maybe it only send $\xi$ to some multiple of $C$ (that would be strange though).